# Issues in sending FormData through ajax using Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am using `FormData` to send `multipart/form-data` and getting it value in PHP, it works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

here is my JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    data: new FormData($("#form")[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
    }
});
```

My HTML code,

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form"> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="name" name="name">   
     <input type="file" id="resourceFile" name="resourceFile"> 
</form>
```

Here is my Php code

```
echo $_POST["name"]  // name field is in form

In chrome I am getting value for name but in Firefox it's saying 
Undefined index: name.


This i am getting on print_r($_POST) for Firefox 
Array ( [-----------------------------183019406712953243052078205169 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "name" sdgdxgf -----------------------------183019406712953243052078205169-- ) 

This i am getting on print_r($_POST) for Chrome 
Array ( [name] => sdgdxgf )
```

Comment: Which firefox version are you using? Besides, please share your HTML form aswell.

Comment: I am using Firefox 45.0 for Ubuntu, 
Here is my HTML form

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="name" name="name">
 <input type="file" id="resourceFile" name="resourceFile">
</form>


and 
data: new FormData($("#form")[0])  i am using.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the html, that way it can be formatted and easier to read :)

Comment: If you try `print_r($_POST);` in the php this might help with debugging

Comment: This i am getting on print_r($_POST) for Firefox

Array
(
    [-----------------------------183019406712953243052078205169
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "name"

sdgdxgf
-----------------------------183019406712953243052078205169--

)

This i am getting on print_r($_POST) for Chrome

Array ( [name] => sdgdxgf )

Comment: Formatted question with posting HTML given by OP by comment

Comment: This is wrong: `data: new FormData("form")`. According with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) you must to pass by argument the DOM object, not a string:  `data: new FormData(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0])`.

Comment: yes, i am using data: new FormData($("#form")[0])

Comment: You have to append the data and send. Please check the  link
[Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: checked with using append, still same issue. Actually it was working before(2 weeks back) but now it's not working anymore